# Imputing missing values by mean by id column in R

Tags: r

This is fairly straight forward but i am unable to do it. My data frame has a id variable which is repeating. For same id I want to replace the NAs in other continuous variable(rating and sur) with their corresponding mean. can anyone pls suggest

```
ID rating Sur
101 60 0.7687
101 78 NA
101 NA 0.765
102 60 NA
102 NA 0.654 
102 75 0.435
103 NA 0.576
103 68 0.875
103 70 NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the mean, you could use dplyr syntax:

```
df = structure(list(ID = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 103L,103L, 103L), 
                    rating = c(60L, 78L, NA, 60L, NA, 75L, NA, 68L, 70L), 
                    Sur = c(0.7687, NA, 0.765, NA, 0.654, 0.435, 0.576, 0.875, NA)), 
               .Names = c("ID", "rating", "Sur"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-9L))


library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(rating = ifelse(is.na(rating), mean(rating, na.rm = TRUE), rating),
         Sur = ifelse(is.na(Sur), mean(Sur, na.rm = TRUE), Sur))


     ID rating     Sur
  <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1   101   60.0 0.76870
2   101   78.0 0.76685
3   101   69.0 0.76500
4   102   60.0 0.54450
5   102   67.5 0.65400
6   102   75.0 0.43500
7   103   69.0 0.57600
8   103   68.0 0.87500
9   103   70.0 0.72550
```

for other imputations you can look at packages like mi, mice, caret, amelia or simputation. And I'm probably forgetting a lot of others. Personally I like the simplicity of simputation.

For example median imputation is just one line:
`impute_median(df, rating + Sur ~ ID)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use for loops for find mean and replacing them with NA for unique ids

```
for(i in unique(df$ID)){
  df$rating[df$ID==i] <- ifelse(is.na(df$rating[df$ID==i]), mean(df$rating[df$ID==i],na.rm=T), df$rating)
  df$Sur[df$ID==i] <- ifelse(is.na(df$Sur[df$ID==i]), mean(df$Sur[df$ID==i],na.rm=T), df$Sur)
}

 ID rating     Sur
1 101   60.0 0.76870
2 101   78.0 0.76685
3 101   69.0 0.76500
4 102   60.0 0.54450
5 102   67.5 0.76685
6 102   69.0 0.76500
7 103   69.0 0.76870
8 103   78.0 0.76685
9 103   69.0 0.72550
```

Answer (score 1):

With the current version of `simputation` you can impute group means with the following trick:

```
impute_lm(df, rating ~ 1 | id)
```

This is linear regression imputation without predictors (hence: mean). The grouping makes sure group means are imputed.

Using `simputation` (>=0.2.1) [not on cran yet] you can do:

```
impute_proxy(df, rating ~ mean(rating,na.rm=TRUE) | id)
```

At the moment this is not on CRAN but you can install it from the [drat](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=drat) repo as described [here](https://github.com/markvanderloo/simputation#materials)